# How do i remove an un-needed Key from a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, graphql, silverstripe

I am new to javascript, and I am using SilverStripe, with GraphQL, which is giving me edges and nodes:

This is the array full of objects:

```
Genre: [
  { ID: "1", Title: "English", StudySubject: { "edges": [ { "node": { "ID": "4", "Title": "English"}}]}},
  { ID: "2", Title: "Maths", StudySubject: { "edges": [ { "node": { "ID": "4", "Title": "Maths"}}]}},
]
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to remove the unneeded edge, and node from each object so I have less dot notation on my frontend?

I would ideally like it to look like

```
Genre: [
  { ID: "1", Title: "English", StudySubject: { "ID": "4", "Title": "English"}},
  { ID: "2", Title: "Maths", StudySubject: { "ID": "4", "Title": "Maths"}},
]
```

Comment: You're having repeated keys in object, can you check once you posted fine data ?

Comment: There can only be one unique key in an object

Comment: You have an error in your input array.

Comment: I have corrected the input object you have provided and added the JSON manipulation in the below code.
https://jsfiddle.net/ulric_469/fk38pjeq/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input data is inaccurate. You cannot have repeated keys at the same level in a JSON data structure. The below answer is with modifications to your data structure.

```js
const data = [
  {
    ID: 1, 
    Subject: 
      {
        edge : [
          {node: {ID : 1, Title: "English"}}
        ]
      }
  }, 
  {
    ID: 2, 
    Subject: {
        edge: [
           {node: {ID: 1, Title: "Maths"}}
        ]
     }
  }
];

const result = data.map(x => ({...x, Subject: x.Subject.edge[0].node}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yeah your right, I was trying to just flick the question out before i went home. I should have proof read it. I'll edit it but also  check your answer thanks!